# How to increase laser/light frequency?

Tags: frequency

I know energy & frequency is equal to each other so if i increase energy i increase frequency. if i add more voltage into my medium it should increase the frequency but let say i add more energy into my system lets say its a gas and its emitting white hot light. I increase the energy but the color remain the same. But if the frequency was increasing wouldn't the color change? Or is it the fact that white light is the mixture of all colors so the frequency is increasing its just i don't see it with the naked eye? Is increasing voltage enough to add energy into my medium or is there another way?

Comment: Energy and frequency are not inherently equal. You can get more energy by increasing the intensity of the light as well. Especially lasers will not change their frequency but the intensity if you put more energy into them. But your question is a bit confusing, are you using a laser or joule heating to make something hot?

Comment: @Arsenal I think the OP is getting things mixed up, and heard/was told that the frequency of a photon and it's energy are in direct relationship (defined by the Planck Constant), which is true, but is mixing the energy of single photons with energy of the system as a whole.

Comment: @Joren Vaes what do you mean by that? So photons can all have different energies?

Comment: @user178750 check my answer below for more details

Comment: In a laser, pumping more energy in just gives you more photons, but each has the same energy (frequency).

Comment: This is a physics question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a physics question and has nothing to do with the design of electrical circuits. Feel free to get a mod to move it to physics.SE after you check for on-topicness at that site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing the energy of the laser as a whole and the energy of the photons in the light.

As you say, the energy of a photon is exactly proportional to the wavelength or frequency of that photon. If you have a higher energy photon, it will have a shorter wavelength. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy):

''
The equation for photon energy is

$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

Where \$E\$ is photon energy, \$h\$ is the [Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant), \$c\$ is the speed of light in vacuum and \$λ\$ is the photon's wavelength. As \$h\$ and \$c\$ are both physical constants, photon energy changes with direct relation to wavelength \$λ\$.''

In most [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser) - which is short for **light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation** (maybe even all, but I am not an expert on lasers) each photon is emitted by electrons that jump between orbitals (in lasers, this happens during a process called [Stimulated Emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission) - the key to the concept of lasers), which means they decrease in energy. To do so, they must get rid of this excess energy, which they do by emission of a photon, which has this exact amount of energy. This means that all photons that are created by the many electrons making these jumps have the same energy and thus the same wavelength, and as a result, lasers have a very monochromatic (= a single wavelength) spectrum.

When you increase the energy consumed by a laser (perhaps a laser diode?), these orbital jumps are still the same - the photons don't suddenly get more energy. However, you increase the amount of photons created ,and as such the amount of radiation energy being generated by the device. The wavelength does not change.

Also, you see to be confusing [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) with [lasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser) radiation. These are two different things. Black body radiation is generated by random energy jumps that emit photons of various wavelengths. Their distribution is discribed by Planck's law (the same guy from the constant earlier in this answer). As we increase the heat, the "peak" of this radiation also increases. This process is also where the term "Color temperature" comes from. This is different from laser radiation, as it contains a continuous spectrum of light, instead of discrete spectral lines found in lasing radiation.

In short, I think you are confusing a few concepts, and perhaps you should look up some more information in the links provided here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning also black body radiation.

Comment: The laser frequency is uniquely determined by the quantum energy levels in the lasing transition. This can perhaps be manipulated a tiny bit via statistical thermodynamics, by a few 100'ths of a Hz, since the bolzmann part (kT) increases with temperature, you can heat/cool the laser some. But you won't notice the difference.

Comment: @StianYttervik Yes, the wavelength of the photons is a bit variable, but for the level of detail in this question and answer I think it is reasonable to ignore these effects.

Comment: Thanks for writing this complete answer - covers all the points I had in mind when writing my comment. Just a small addition (because few person realize it): white glowing is not the hottest "colour" you can get, if you heat further the glow will shift to blue - but you are beyond 6000K at that point, which means almost everything will have vaporized at that point.

Comment: @Arsenal Yes, good point. Related factoid: I seem to remember that manufacturers of detergents made for clothes added certain compounds to their product that would be slightly luminescent and emit a slight blue-ish color. This would offset any slight yellowing of white fabric and make it look "whiter" than it actually was (and thus look cleaner compared to fabric washed with detergent that did not contain this). However, I don't have any source on this so it could just be an urban legend.

Comment: Those things are called [optical brighteners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_brightener) and are not exclusively used for laundry but in many other things as well.

Comment: I really did confuse the two.. Sorry about that still learning. Lets go back to lasers and the stimulated emission. You stated if i increase The energy it will just create more photon. The energy it already had will remain the same, but how can i increase the energy that will be absorbed by electron the starting energy of my laser. If you have any more resource to learn from please share. I have a lot more learning to do.

Comment: The energy of each photon is defined by the bandgaps of the material used. This is why you will find many different materials used for various different optical wavelengths. (Helium-neon, CO2, Ruby, etc). You can't significantly impact the spectrum emitted (at least not easily), and definitely not by just pumping in more energy.

Comment: Ah that kind of what i thought. Thanks guys big help

Comment: Some laser mediums have multiple possible lasing transitions, but selecting between them is a matter of causing the cavity to only have meaningful gain at the one you want. YAG for example has IIRC about 3 with meaningful gain in the IR, while an old school Argon/Krypton mixed gas laser has 7 or so in the viable spectrum (But horrible power efficiency). In addition there are some (generally IR) laser mediums that have fairly broadband gain and that can be used to build a tunable laser source by placing a diffraction grating or interferometer in the cavity.

Comment: @StianYttervik, More like by a few MHz or GHz. Just getting a laser line width into the kHz range is no easy feat. Tuning to 10's of millihertz would require some very special equipment and care.